# Akka actor externalizing deployment configuration

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka

I am instantiating a Actor in a play 2.1.5 application using

```
lazy val ref = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[BackgroundProcessorActor], name = "background-processor")
```

I have a properties file that specifies the following configuration

```
application {
  akka {
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
        }
      }

      background-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
        }
      }

      deployment = {
        /background-processor = {
          dispatcher = background-dispatcher
          router = round-robin
          nr-of-instances = 128
        }

        /solr_asset_updater = {
          dispatcher = default-dispatcher
        }

        /solr_asset_log_updater = {
          dispatcher = default-dispatcher
        }

        /change_queue_processor = {
          dispatcher = default-dispatcher
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I spent some time reading the docs and the source code for play. However the deployment settings for `background-processor` specifically `router = round-robin` and `nr-of-instances = 128` do not seem to be taking.

Is it necessary to specify

```
lazy val ref = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[BackgroundProcessorActor].withRouter(FromConfig()), name = "background-processor")
```

which to me seems redundant. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the question

Is it necessary to specify (FromConfig)

```
lazy val ref = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[BackgroundProcessorActor].withRouter(FromConfig()), name = "background-processor")
```

The answer from the docs in akka

> The decision whether to create a router at all, on the other hand, must be taken within the code, i.e. you cannot make something a router by external configuration alone (see below for details).

In effect requiring the use of *withRouter* and the specification of router option either in code or from config using *FromConfig*

Answer (score 1):

The actor system in Play's Akka plugin is named `application`, but uses the top-level configuration (not a sub-config). You can test this easily by setting the log level.

```
akka {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"

  actor {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, however addressing that did not fix the issue, since FromConfig is required. You did lead me in the right direction

Comment: Ok, but the rest (dispatcher for example) should work automatically.